# Barcode Scanner intent in my activity

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing

Is there any way to put a Zxing intent inside a part of my activity? For example I want to keep on screen some text and buttons + Barcode Scanner intent below them.
Any examples/tutorials would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the ZXing page on using their intentintegrator? http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Yes, but my problem is not scanning but putting Zxing inside my app so user can see part of my app and menu at same time.

Comment: An `Intent` is not part of a user interface.

Comment: You mean they can see your app while scanning - sort of split screen? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: So how to solve my problem? Would be it activity(zxing) in activity(my app)? Is that even possible? Yes, as split screen.

Answer (score -1):

I remember I made something like this before. You should try to :
- Create an `Activity`. (MyCaptureActivity for example) 
- Copy-paste the content of the class `CaptureActivity` in the `Activity` created above.
- Create a layout XML file. (mycapture.xml for example)
- Copy-paste the content of the file capture.xml in the file created above. 
- Find the line `setContentView(R.layout.capture);` and replace it by `setContentView(R.layout.mycapture);` in MyCaptureActivity.
- Then, you can add your texts and your buttons in the layout.
- And you can modify the activity to react as you want and to remove some views.

Comment: As I copy Zxing `CaptureActivity` I obtain tons of errors due to not having rest of Zxing activities.

Comment: Add the Zxing library into your folder libs of your project.

Comment: Most likely I don't know how to do that (or I'm missing something). Isn't there any tutorial about that? Personally I couldn't find any but maybe someone knows any?

Comment: Download this archive : http://zxing.googlecode.com/files/ZXing-2.1.zip. Extract the folder android in the folder of your workspace. In eclipse import the project in the folder you just extracted. Right-click on the new project, click Properties > Android, check that `isLibrary` is checked. Right-click on your project, click Properties > Android add the project Zxing as a library. Clean your workspace.

Comment: Still something wrong. I make library(no errors in it), add library(zxing) to my project and make `MyCaptureActivity`and put content of `CaptureActivity` there = many errors. First is `The import com.google.zxing.client.android.camera cannot be resolved`

Comment: Try to clean your workspace, delete all the import and re-import all the classes (CTRL+SHIFT+O).

Comment: After one more importing android from Zxing I got many @Override errors. Is there any way to fix them all or just I messed something up again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20049/discussion-between-primosz-and-ydelouis)

Comment: @yDelouis can you post the whole project on any you blog or on git please I need it too